# Insert HTML TAG before and after selected text positionin C#

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Today i want to create something like simple HTML editor in C# win-forms. It should be add specific tag to the selected text in richbox. So my design is really simple .
[image]

And i want to select for example last letter which is "d" and add  tag so final result should look like

[image]

So i tried to use Replace function like

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(richTextBox1.SelectedText, $"<red>{richTextBox1.SelectedText}</red>");
```

But it will replace all others "d" letters. Any ideas how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SelectedText returns the string that is selected.
So, if you select "d", it will return only the string "d", so it will replace everything.

you can replace only the selected strings by doing the following

```
var position = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
var replacedText = $"<red>{richTextBox1.SelectedText}</red>";
richTextBox1.SelectedText = replacedText;
richTextBox1.Select(position, replacedText.Length);
richTextBox1.Focus();
```

Comment: I would have fully expected this code to replace all cases of the `SelectedText` (i.e. if the letter `d` appeared multiple times, it would replace all of them), but that doesn't appear to be the case, making this a super easy solution.

Comment: How to keep highlighting selected text when focus is lost in textbox in c# because when i clicked on button highlighting selected text is lost. How to fix that?